# When will the next Intellibot for PyCharm be released?

Tags: plugins, pycharm, robotframework, intellibot, intellibot-robot

It is September, 2023 now. I have the following installed on my MacOS:
Python: 3.11
Pip: 23.2.1
PyCharm: PyCharm 2023.2.1 (Community Edition)

- Build #PC-232.9559.58, built on August 23, 2023
- Runtime version: 17.0.8+7-b1000.8 x86_64
- VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
- macOS 13.5.1
- GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
- Non-Bundled Plugins: com.millennialmedia.intellibot@SeleniumLibrary Patched (0.10.143.381)

Robot Framework: 6.1.1

Robot Framework-pythonlibcore: 4.2.0

Robot Framework Seleniumlibrary: 6.1.1

Selenium: 4.11.2

I have having problems with the Intellibot plugin for PyCharm in that the auto-complete feature is not working and I get an IDE error as seen below:
`com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: Please, do not use constructor injection: it slows down initialization and may lead to performance problems (requestorClass=com.millennialmedia.intellibot.psi.RobotPsiManager)). See https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/plugin-services.html for details. [Plugin: com.millennialmedia.intellibot@SeleniumLibrary Patched]`

From looking online, it seems it might be that the Intellibot plugin does not support PyCharm 2023. Does anyone know when Intellibot will have a new version out?

I have tried the intellibot.jar file here, but to no avail:
[https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot](https://stackoverflow.com)

I have also tried nearly all other solutions online, but all the solutions are for older versions of PyCharm. I have tried older PyCharms, but still no go, so I decided to just use the latest version and wait for a new Intellibot version.

Also, does anyone know of any other plugins that do the same job as Intellibot but is more stable? Thank you.

Comment: It is not a direct answer, but just in case: there are other plugins available for RobotFramework x Pycharm. E.g. I've used [Hyper RobotFramework Support](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16382-hyper-robotframework-support) for some time and It is quite good, imho

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and I have installed the following plugins in PyCharm:

1. IntelliBot Robot Framework Support
2. Robot Framework Language Server
   and just restarted Pycharm, and I checked. Everything is working as expected now.